# How to create duplicate key in Javascript Object to match the rule of MongoDB multiple search string?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I try to use MongoDB to operate searching of multiple searching strings.

The rule of multiple searching strings on MongoDB

```
db.meals.find({mealName: /fish/, mealName: /rice/, mealName: /spicy/})
```

The challenge of mine is that objects in Javascript can't not have the same key in same object.

I tried to way like this:

```
const str = "fish rice spicy";
const transform = (searchInput) => {
  const searchField = {}
  let searchArray = searchInput.split(" ");
  searchArray = searchArray.map((item)=>{
    const fixKey = "mealName";
    searchField[fixKey] = new RegExp(item);
  })
  return searchField;
}
console.log(transform(str)); // {mealName: /spicy/}
```

In this condition

How do I conform the format of MongoDB multiple searching string in Javascript?

Comment: Do you mean $or: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `mongoDB` `$in` like this

```
const strArray = "fish rice spicy".split(" ");
db.meals.find({ mealName: {$in: strArray } })
```

It will fetches all records where `mealName` will matches any of the `strArray` item.